# What sports did Flash Gordon play?

Tags: character-development, flash-gordon

I know that Flash Gordon, when he first appeared in Alex Raymond's original comic strip, was a polo player. In the 1980 movie, he was an American Football player for the New York Jets. After that, in the 1988 DC comic book series he was a professional basketball player.

**Does anyone know of any other sports he is portrayed as playing in his other appearances?** I don't mean sports he was able to play, rather ones he was portrayed as playing professionally.

Comment: Other than the animated Defenders cartoon, I think that pretty much covers his appearances LOL.

Comment: There was also a film serialization in the 1930's starring Buster Crabbe but don't know if it had references to his sports background. Maybe someone has seen the serialization and can address. There was also a radio serialization but that supposedly adhered strongly to the Sunday strip being published at the time.

Comment: There are many more incarnations of Flash; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Gordon#Flash_Gordon_.281954.E2.80.9355_live-action.29

Comment: Minor nit in the question:  He was unlikely to have played polo professionally; to the contrary, rumor had it that for the Yale polo team, the cost to board a polo pony was higher than tuition for a human.  (Disclaimer:  _I_ did not get my nickname playing polo there.)